# Cannot find module 'workbox-webpack-plugin'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack

Suddenly my react project is crashed, everytime i use npm start i got below message:

```
PS C:\able-pro-material-react> npm start 

> able-pro-material-react@9.1.0 start
> react-app-rewired start

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'workbox-webpack-plugin'
Require stack:
- C:\able-pro-material-react\config-overrides.js
- C:\able-pro-material-react\node_modules\react-app-rewired\config-overrides.js
- C:\able-pro-material-react\node_modules\react-app-rewired\scripts\start.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\able-pro-material-react\config-overrides.js:2:23)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\able-pro-material-react\\config-overrides.js',
    'C:\\able-pro-material-react\\node_modules\\react-app-rewired\\config-overrides.js',
    'C:\\able-pro-material-react\\node_modules\\react-app-rewired\\scripts\\start.js'
  ]
}

Node.js v18.16.1
```

`npm install --save-dev webpack`

i tried to use npm i -g webpack webpack-cli as well npm install --save-dev webpack but nothing changed.

Comment: The error is about `workbox-webpack-plugin` and not about `webpack`. So did you install the `workbox-webpack-plugin`package?

Comment: You right it works :)